# Display a rounded count of Custom Post Type

Tags: count

I'd like display a rounded up count of the total number of custom post types.

Currently I am using this

```
    <?php
    $count_posts = wp_count_posts('listing');
    $published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
    echo $published_posts;
    ?>
```

but would like to round the number to nearest hundred, so for example,

- if the count was 120 it would show 100
- if the count was 158 it would show 200
- if the count was 1088 it would show 1000

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question not related to `WordPress`, but you will get solution by follow

PHP Custom functions: add into `functions.php`

```
    if( !function_exists('ceiling') )
    {
        function ceiling($number, $significance = 1)
        {
            return ( is_numeric($number) && is_numeric($significance) ) ? (round($number/$significance)*$significance) : false;
        }
    }
    if( !function_exists('ceilNumber') )
    {
        function ceilNumber($number)
        {
            return ceiling($number, (int)'1'.str_repeat('0', strlen($number)-1));
        }
    }
```

Call above function into your code

```
$count_posts = wp_count_posts('listing');
$published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
echo ceilNumber($published_posts);
```